# Table.column_names returns old values in a migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm doing a migration where I rename the columns: currency becomes legacy_currency etc. The problem is that when I'm trying to get the column names for the table, it returns old values.

Tried using `reset_column_information` and it didn't work. Also tried the following:

```
Model.connection.schema_cache.clear!
Model.reset_column_information
```

Doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

An excerpt from the code:

```
currency_columns = table_class.column_names.grep(/currency/).map(&:to_sym)
currency_columns.each do |currency_col|
  rename_column table, col, "legacy_#{col}".to_sym
end
...
table_class.column_names #still has the old values
```

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Also, what does your migration file look like?

Comment: I've pasted an excerpt from the migration file

Comment: Before calling the .column_names, doesn't seem to do anything though

Comment: Since it's more complicated than rename_column :purchases, :currency, :legacy_currency. Be sure to check all inputs ("table", "col").

Comment: You can use `puts` in a migration.  Try outputting some info inside the loop, which can help convince you (and us) that your rename call is actually happening.

Comment: I see the output of the rename calls in my console (it's a migration, remember), that part of the script is working fine.

Comment: Since I'm doing the migration for more than one model, I've went through the other ones and `reset_column_information` does seem to work for all but one. I'll investigate why it's like that and post the answer later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've investigated that the issue only appeared on one of the models, I've debugged it and found that we were using an old(ish) version of [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) (3.3.0), which used cache for the `columns` method, which was called by `column_names` in ActiveRecord.

Updating the gem to 3.5.0 resolved the issue.